# symfony errors with form and renderLabel

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony-1.4, render

I am new with symfony1.4.20 . This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#user_username").focus();
    });
</script>

<div id="login">
<h2>Please Login... </h2>
<form action="<?php echo url_for('login/index') ?>" method="POST">
    <?php echo $form->renderHiddenField()?>
    <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors()?>
    <?php echo $form->['username']->renderLabel()?>
    <?php echo $form->['username']?>
    <?php echo $form->['password']->renderLabel()?>
    <?php echo $form->['password']?>
    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" />
    <?php if($form->hasErrors()): ?>
    <div id="errorBox">
        Check the following errors: <br />
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors() as $error ): ?>
                <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
            <?php endforeach ; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
</form>
```

Than i got message error like this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in D:\Lab\WhoDoWhat\apps\userlogin\modules\login\templates\indexSuccess.php on line 12
```

it's mean it's start errors on line

```
<?php echo $form->['username']->renderLabel()?>
```

Any one have any solution for me ?? thanks

Comment: warning! Symfony 1.xx is not supported anymore and is old. When you wanna start with Symfony, I recommend to use Symfony 2.xx.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` is used to reference a method or property. When using the `[]` syntax you shouldn't use it. Remove the `->` so it becomes:

```
<?php echo $form['username']->renderLabel()?>
```

Comment: Hmm... How clever you are ? i compare it again and again with original source code but i still can't see what difference

Comment: I removed the `->` after the word `$form`.

Comment: Please remember to give him accepcted answer then, so other people can utilize this thread when they have problems and find this. And take a look at my comment under your question please.